# SELECT value non-existing on the first JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the total current sales for the month by category. I also wanted to display all the `category_name` (including cars) even though an `item_id` of that `category_id` is not present on my `sales_tbl` or gives $0.00 sales like..

```
category_name  |  subTotalSales_ofMonth
---------------------------------------
   appliances  |    33 000
     cars      |         0
      IT       |   150 000
```

Running this

```
SELECT
c.category_name,
SUM(amount) AS subTotalSales_ofMonth   
FROM sales_tbl sa
INNER JOIN item_out_tbl io
ON io.item_id=sa.item_id
INNER JOIN category_tbl c
ON io.category_id=c.category_id
WHERE MONTH(sa.date_sold) >= $month)
GROUP BY io.category_id
```

gives me

```
category_name  |  subTotalSales_ofMonth
---------------------------------------
   appliances  |    33 000
      IT       |   150 000
```

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: yes, still fail i think i should use key=NULL?

Comment: No, @D4VID's right. You need an OUTER JOIN. The LEFT variety is particularly popular. But if you're still struggling, provide proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an outer join. Since all your categories are stored in the `category_tbl` table, that table should be on the outer side of the join. One way to make it so is to change the order of your joins and use `LEFT JOIN` in both cases. You will also need to move the `WHERE` condition to one of the `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT
  c.category_name,
  SUM(amount) AS subTotalSales_ofMonth   
FROM
  category_tbl AS c
  LEFT JOIN item_out_tbl AS io ON io.category_id = c.category_id
  LEFT JOIN sales_tbl    AS sa ON io.item_id = sa.item_id
                              AND MONTH(sa.date_sold) >= $month
GROUP BY
  c.category_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT c.category_name,
SUM(amount) AS subTotalSales_ofMonth   
FROM sales_tbl sa
    LEFT JOIN item_out_tbl io ON io.item_id=sa.item_id
    LEFT JOIN category_tbl c ON io.category_id=c.category_id
WHERE MONTH(sa.date_sold) >= $month)
GROUP BY c.category_id
```

Comment: @Strawberry nicely updated the answer - the grouping was done on the incorrect field, try it now

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be c.category_name, but MySQL forgives the aberration.

Answer (score 0):

Full outer join will give you your desired result (although it will also grab NULLs from category_name):

```
SELECT c.category_name, SUM(amount) AS subTotalSales_ofMonth   
FROM sales_tbl sa
    FULL OUTER JOIN item_out_tbl io ON io.item_id=sa.item_id
    FULL OUTER JOIN category_tbl c ON io.category_id=c.category_id
WHERE MONTH(sa.date_sold) >= $month)
GROUP BY io.category_id
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) for a guide on all the joins.